# Replace this Hex chars from string in PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, replace, preg-replace, hex

I'm generating an XML from data that comes from database (and some JSON feeds).

I'm having some problems with some texts that contains some hex chars that are breaking my XML.

For example, see this screenshot of the error I get from Chrome:
[image: XML error]

I identified the hex characters that are giving me problems (I believe they're called control characters). And these are:

```
0x03
0x05
0x16
0x0E
```

How can I replace those characters with PHP before printing them on my XML output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

More than just those characters will break it...

```
preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1f]/', '?', $s);
```

Comment: What about the other control characters from `\x7f` to `\xc2\x9f` (see http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

Comment: Another control set starts from x80 (or x7F if you want to include it) to 9F.
\xc2 you wrote as hex means "Controlset 2" in your link. in short c2
So its Control Set 2 \x9F. For clarity

Comment: You are replacing everything with `?`, is it possible to replace them with hex code of same character? e.g. `\x00` to `\\x00` and ...

Answer (score 5):

The characters you list are indeed control characters, all placed in the [C0 set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes):

```
0x03 - ETX  End of Text
0x05 - ENQ  Enquiry
0x0E - SO   Shift Out
0x16 - SYN  Synchronous Idle
```

You should verify how these characters went into the string. I can not really suggest to remove them (if you plan to remove them, use at least a substitution character, do not just remove them), but being a bit more conservative here as those aren't invalid unicode, just convert them to numeric entities ([this has been successfully done here, too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10095728/367456)):

```
$pairs = array(
    "\x03" => "&#x03;",
    "\x05" => "&#x05;",
    "\x0E" => "&#x0E;",
    "\x16" => "&#x16;",
);
$xml = strtr($xml, $pairs);
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks Hakre, I tried you suggestion, but those control characters appeared like this on my XML data: http://d.pr/TnO5
To avoid this I opted to use preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1f]/', '', $s); to remove it completely.

Comment: Yes, inside CDATA would need un-CDATA'ing those areas first. Additionally re-reading your question, technically the characters given are not invalid UTF-8, just invalid SGML.

Answer (score 0):

If the input promises to be of a certain character set, you can probably use one of the character set encoding functions to retain the most possible data (without pesky missing characters; text can look messed up without them!).  It's possible that utf8_encode might help you, but only if you know that the text is ISO-8859-1.  Otherwise, you might have more luck with iconv, assuming you have it installed.

The best thing about iconv, in my opinion, is the ability to use transliteration if you're downconverting from UTF to a less capable character set.  If you're encoding to UTF-8, though, you'd probably want something like this:

```
$resultText = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $inputText );
```

Comment: A valiant try, but they are actually valid in both ISO 8859-1 *and* UTF-8. It's only Chrome that's breaking.

Answer (score -1):

```
preg_replace("/[[^0]\x03-[^0]\x05\-[^0]\x16-[^0]\x0E]/", '', $string);
```

Comment: `[[^0]...]`? What should this do?

Comment: Exclude every character except the number 0

Comment: You can't have character classes inside character classes. You also can't have multiple `-` inside a character class. The regex is invalid.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to regex patterns, but was just trying to help with what i know. I probably should've tested it before i posted.